# Problem with vertical space in enumerate environment

Tags: lists, vertical-alignment, enumerate

I have a problem regarding the vertical space between `\item` and an image. I use the following code and the image doesn't move vertical as it should. Why is that? And how can I fix it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item

\begin{enumerate}
\item

\vspace{0.3cm}

\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{2.2.a.png}

\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Edit I: Also I had deleted by mistake the `\usepackage{graphicx}` and it still compiled without error! How is that possible and why?

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence.
l.13 \includegraphics

Comment: Sorry I deleted it by mistake while copying it.

Comment: You can edit the question to fix it, add `draft` at same time as no one has an image of that name,

Comment: I edited it. You can change it with a random image in order to compile it.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item

\begin{enumerate}
\item


\adjustbox{valign=t}{\rule{1cm}{2cm}}

\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why doesn't work without any fixes? What's the problem?

Comment: @Adam It does work, it just doesn't give what you want (a) images align on their baselines and you want a top alignment and (b) vspace does nothing there as latex is busy removing space to make nested enumeration labels line up.

Comment: What do you mean in b?

Comment: @Adam when you nest enumerations latex goes to some lengths to make the 1  the (a) and the text of the actual item to all come on the same line.

Comment: I am sorry but what does that mean especially when you say that "goes to some lengths". What does it do?? Why \vspace doesn't do anything?